# Volume of a solid generated by rotating a curve around a given line

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

The curve is $y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, on the interval [1, 4] and the line is x = -1.

The integral I have set up using the cylindrical shell method is
$$ 2\pi \int_1^4 \frac{x+1}{1+x^2}\, dx $$

but I'm not sure if it is correct. I'm confused about whether I should subtract the line from the x value or the x value from the line to get the radius since the results are different.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It can be helpful to ask yourself about test values. What should the radius of the shell be at $x=1$? It should be 2. What should it be at $x=4$? It should be 3 greater than what it is at $x=1$, i.e. the radius should be $5$. So a radius of $x+1$ passes these checks, and using a different sign wouldn't.

Comment: @thorimur Perfect, that was exactly the kind of logical check I was looking for.